# Error: Reference Nbr. cannot be found in the system.."}

Tags: acumatica

I customized the ARPaymentEntry  in which it creates a Journal Voucher Entry with created Credit Memo, it retrieves the Credit Memo applies the open invoice that is also applied in the current payment. when I create the instance to call the Credit Memo and add the Invoice in  ARAdjust table, an error occurs when trying to insert it, giving a Reference Nbr cannot be found in the system, although when I'm trying to manually applying it I could see the open invoice.

```
    public void ReleaseCreditMemo(string refNbr)
    {
        try
        {
            ARPaymentEntry docGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARPaymentEntry>();
            List<ARRegister> list = new List<ARRegister>();
            ARPayment payment;

            ARRegister invoice = PXSelect<ARRegister, Where<ARRegister.docType, Equal<Required<ARRegister.docType>>, And<ARRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARRegister.refNbr>>>>>.Select(docGraph, ARInvoiceType.CreditMemo, refNbr);

            docGraph.Document.Current = PXSelect<ARPayment, Where<ARPayment.docType, Equal<Required<ARPayment.docType>>, And<ARPayment.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARPayment.refNbr>>>>>.Select(docGraph, ARInvoiceType.CreditMemo, refNbr);

            payment = docGraph.Document.Current;

            list.Add(payment);

            foreach (ISARWhTax item in ARWhLine.Select())
            {
                decimal? _CuryAdjgAmt = payment.CuryOrigDocAmt > invoice.CuryDocBal ? invoice.CuryDocBal : payment.CuryOrigDocAmt;
                decimal? _CuryAdjgDiscAmt = payment.CuryOrigDocAmt > invoice.CuryDocBal ? 0m : invoice.CuryDiscBal;
                ARAdjust adj = new ARAdjust();
                adj.AdjdBranchID = item.AdjdBranchID;
                adj.AdjdDocType = ARInvoiceType.Invoice;
                adj.AdjdRefNbr = item.AdjdRefNbr;
                adj.AdjdCustomerID = item.CustomerID;
                adj.AdjdDocDate = invoice.DocDate;
                adj.CuryAdjgAmt = _CuryAdjgAmt;
                adj.CuryAdjdDiscAmt = _CuryAdjgDiscAmt;

                if (docGraph.Document.Current.CuryUnappliedBal == 0m && docGraph.Document.Current.CuryOrigDocAmt > 0m)
                {
                    throw new PXLoadInvoiceException();
                }
                //This line code below OCCURS THE ERROR
                docGraph.Adjustments.Insert(adj);
            }
            docGraph.Save.Press();
            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(docGraph, delegate() { ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(list, false); });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new PXException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out it that after the code below executes it does not immediately updates the View. So what I did is to execute my code at ARPayment_RowSelected  event with a conditional statement if the document is released.

```
 PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this.Base, delegate() { ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(list, false); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the selector of the field causing the error ("Reference Nbr.") as having a selector on a field will validate the entered value to the selector's select statement (unless validatevalue=false for the selector). Maybe the selector will give you some pointers as to what is missing or causing the validation to fail.